# MVC4 minification and bundle on publish?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, publish, bundling-and-minification

I am creating an install for an MVC4 site that will be installed at customer sites.  I do not want the javascript to exist on disk "not minified". Is there a way to use the existing bundling framework to bundle and minify on publish?  Right now the files are served minified but are stored in their original readable format.  Prior to MVC4 I was using a build script to do this, I hope to not have to go back to that.  Is this possible?

Comment: You mean have the publish step remove the non minified files, keeping just minified?

Comment: my source files (except 3rd party libs) are all non-minified.  So publish just copies them out there but I want them to be copied bundled and minified.  This is so I have one button that publishes to my staging site, and another to the install location without having two methods one for each.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this tool will do what you want; for what you're trying to do you'll probably want to use the MSBUILD-related functionality:

http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/

Comment: BTW, I found the reference to that tool at this site, which talks in much greater detail about such things:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx

Comment: Good link provided on this, I have used google closure to minify my .js before but what I am looking for is to utilize the existing built in minify to just do that on disk as well at the publish destination.